# Loopback, dump request

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm developing rest API via Loopback framework. I  want to dump incoming request when someone sends `POST` request to model with remote method. I want to do this even if key does not match specified name in *arg*, `argument`. So, basically print `POST` request in console whatever it contains, something like `var_dump($_POST)` in PHP, for example.

```
someMethod.remoteMethod(
      'pickTrans',
      {
        accepts: {arg: 'argument', type: 'string'},
        returns: {arg: 'response', type:'string'}
      }
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your remote method accept `object` type. This will make it accept any type of argument. Then you can use loopback's `getCurrentContext()` function to get the `context` object and parse the `request` object as done below.

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
module.exports = function(YourModel) {
    ...
    //remote method
    YourModel.someMethod = function(argument, cb) {
        var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext();
        var postRequest = ctx && ctx.req;
        console.log(postRequest); //here's your POST request
        ...
        cb(null, "done");
    };
    someMethod.remoteMethod(
        'pickTrans',
        {
            accepts: {arg: 'argument', type: 'object', http: {source: 'body'}},
            http: {
                path: '/pickTrans',
                type: 'post'
            },
            returns: {arg: 'response', type:'string'}
        }
    );
    ...
};
```

Hope this solves what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is helpful. This trick with object is working.